# How to get my friend's OS information

Tags: internet

I am thinking that is there any way that i can know the OS information of my friend's using internet in ubuntu. Suppose a friend of mine is in my buddy list (gmail, yahoo, facebook, and skype). Is there any way that i can know which os he is using? At least linux, or windows or mac or etc(only name without more details). Also without knowing him. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nmap` which is suggested in this question in superuser stackExchange site. It is basically pinging the computer and analyzing the response message.

- [How can I determine the OS of a remote computer?](https://superuser.com/a/323245/134448)

Installing `nmap` with the command

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

and

using it with `-O` option for one of Google's public DNS address (8.8.4.4) gave me this response

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-11-05 13:29 BDT
Nmap scan report for google-public-dns-b.google.com (8.8.4.4)
Host is up (0.095s latency).
Not shown: 988 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
53/tcp   open   domain
113/tcp  closed ident
135/tcp  closed msrpc
445/tcp  closed microsoft-ds
593/tcp  closed http-rpc-epmap
1300/tcp closed h323hostcallsc
1718/tcp closed h323gatedisc
1719/tcp closed h323gatestat
1720/tcp closed H.323/Q.931
2000/tcp closed cisco-sccp
5004/tcp closed avt-profile-1
5061/tcp closed sip-tls
Device type: general purpose|firewall
Running (JUST GUESSING): Linux 2.6.X (87%), Cisco embedded (85%)
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/h:cisco:ips_4270
Aggressive OS guesses: Linux 2.6.11 - 2.6.18 (87%), Cisco IPS 4270 intrusion prevention system (85%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).
Network Distance: 10 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 56.41 seconds
```

It seems Google DNS is using Linux with CISCO components embedded (as per the output), but it also says no exact OS matches. It is not 100% reliable. Though I think, you can have enough information from the above output.